# "ERROR command failed: npm install --loglevel error" when trying to do "vue create"

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

```
Vue CLI v3.2.1
✨  Creating project in /home/mcaubrey511/portfolio.
  Initializing git repository...
⚙  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...


> yorkie@2.0.0 install /home/mcaubrey511/portfolio/node_modules/yorkie
> node bin/install.js


ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error
```

---

#### Environment info

**System:**

OS: Linux 4.18 Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish)

CPU: (1) x64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.30GHz

**Binaries:**

Node: 10.14.1 - /usr/bin/node

npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/bin/npm

**npmPackages:**

@vue/babel-preset-app:  3.2.0

@vue/cli-overlay:  3.2.0

@vue/cli-plugin-babel: ^3.2.0 => 3.2.0

@vue/cli-plugin-eslint: ^3.2.0 => 3.2.1

@vue/cli-service: ^3.2.0 => 3.2.0

@vue/cli-shared-utils:  3.2.0

@vue/component-compiler-utils:  2.3.0

@vue/preload-webpack-plugin:  1.1.0

@vue/web-component-wrapper:  1.2.0

babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props:  2.0.3

babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx:  4.0.1

eslint-plugin-vue:  4.7.1

vue-eslint-parser:  2.0.3

vue-hot-reload-api:  2.3.1

vue-loader:  15.4.2

vue-style-loader:  4.1.2

vue-template-es2015-compiler:  1.6.0

**npmGlobalPackages:**

@vue/cli: 3.2.1

---

Any idea what's wrong or what I could do to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching the machine I was using to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I am no longer having the problem. I made [an issue on the vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3102) repository and it seems like at least one other person is having a similar problem, but with a different environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `apt-get update` in terminal before installing the `vue/cli`, the issue will be solved.

In a nutshell, `apt-get update` doesn't actually install new versions of software. Instead, it updates the package lists for upgrades for packages that need upgrading, as well as new packages that have just come to the repositories.

> `apt-get update` downloads the package lists from the repositories and "updates" them to get information on the newest versions of packages and their dependencies. It will do this for all repositories and PPAs.